# Create a Custom field for content for adminside as Video

Tags: joomla-3.x, com-content, content, custom-field

I am in need of custom plugin that allow me to add custom fields like Video from admin side for Articles of all category. Can anyone guide me please.

**Video File type (I will select file and that would be saved)**

I have try by creating custom plugin that allow me to add Input type=file but it stores filename of video only, it is not uploading video. can any has an idea from where i can achieve this.

All existing custom field components that i have checked provides Image only not a Video.

We do not have front side website to show this fields only for API purpose.
I want to add Video from admin side for each article it will not shown on front side, we have mobile application integration only.

Is there any option we can upload PDF or Video for each content from any core file...

Comment: Well... from what I heard so far about what's cooking in Joomla oven, I would wait few months for Joomla 3.7 and her new Custom Fields feature.

Answer (score 1):

[Fieldsattach](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/fieldsattach) is one CCK that can add YouTube or Vimeo video fields to your content. The YouTube and Vimeo fields are [free add-ons](http://www.fieldsattach.com/index.php/add-ons/extra-fields).

[DPFields](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/dpfields) which is scheduled to become the core CCK in Joomla 3.7 unfortunately [does not appear to support video fields yet](https://joomla.digital-peak.com/products/dpfields).